# Autocomplete in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I try type `pandas.DataFrame()` in VSCode, but after `(` the suggestion disappear (not showing)

I record my problem here

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kK8yrVuFysN64FhFodKFi3yehAmpDanR

I expect when type `pandas.DataFrame()` still suggestion is showing till I type `()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the file settings.json and set "python.jediEnabled" to true, then once you are inside the parentesis press ctr+space, it will activate the intellisence, look for the wrench icon, those are the parameters.

Comment: Thank you. It veryhelpful. If I want make always activate the intellisence like in spyder where you can search syntax and parameter can show up. Can VS code do that?

Comment: If you mean the type filters for intellisense, Visual Studio Code have not implemented that yet.